# VBAT vs 4V on this circuit. What is the difference?

Tags: circuit-design, sim800

Schematic can be found [here](https://github.com/Xinyuan-LilyGO/LilyGo-T-Call-SIM800/blob/master/schematic/LilyGo-SIM800L-IP5306-20200811.pdf)

I am trying to understand and replicate the schematic.

Why doesn't the author use DVDD4V4 for the ADC and he/she uses VBAT instead?

Can I just connect to ADC the DVDD4V4?

I am not interested in using the "charger" so I am not going to have VBAT at all.. Can I just connect the 4V instead?

[image: extracts]

Answer (score 1):

It appears to me that the creator(s) of the original schematic are trying to **measure** the battery voltage using the ADC. The voltage divider with large resistor values is a big hint. Without a link to the datasheet for the SIM800 that is my best guess.

If you don't want to measure anything with the ADC then you probably don't need to connect any voltage at all to the ADC pin.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the schematic you link to, `DVDD4V4` comes from the output of a switching regulator, and is generated as a stable voltage from the `5V` net.

The `5V` net is in turn generated from a boost converter from the battery voltage `VBAT`.

That means that as the battery voltage decreases, the `DVDD4V4` supply rail stays constant, because the various converters stabilise the voltage.

The ADC appears to be there to measure the battery voltage, so you can measure how it is decreasing to presumably estimate state-of-charge (SOC) of the battery. Measuring `DVDD4V4` would not allow you to see this, as the voltage remains stable due to the regulators.